# How do I execute a stored procedure without parameters in JDBC?

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure without input variables like :

```
 String  sql2 = "{call vivek}" ;
 System.out.println(sql2);
 System.out.println("Executing procedure without parameters");
 stmt = conn.createStatement();
 stmt.executeQuery(sql2);
```

But its throwing an error saying :

```
syntax error at or near "{"
  Position: 1
```

I'm trying to google it but not able to find anything. How do I do it ? By the way it didn't work with callablestatement also

Comment: Well you need to make it work will CallableStatement. Show the code you used back then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not tested:

```
CallableStatement cs = null;
cs = conn.prepareCall("{call vivek}");
cs.executeQuery();
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html

Answer (score 1):

Could not find stored procedure? I will explain what it means when you get this error. Assuming our code is like this:

```
String sp="{call GetUnitReferenceMap}";
stmt=conn.prepareCall(sp);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
currencyMap.put(rs.getString(1).trim(), rs.getString(2).trim());
```

I have 4 DBs (sample1, sample2, sample3), but `stmt` will search location `master` (Default DB) then we will get an Exception.

We should provide DB name, then problem will be resolved::

```
String sp="{call sample1..GetUnitReferenceMap}";
```

Answer (score 1):

It's similar to calling a function without arguments.

```
CallableStatement cat = null;
con = YourConnectionClass.getConnection();
cst = con.prepareCall("{call YOUR_PROCEDURE_NAME()}");
cst.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone but the following code worked for me :

```
sql2 += "{exec "+ proc_name2 +"}" ;
cstmt = conn.prepareCall(sql2);
cstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Here cstmt is the CallableStatement object by the way. And I'm using Postgresql Database hence the above code worked for me